# PHP Form Nested within PHP Form, CAPTCHA instantly fails

Tags: php, validation, captcha

I have a page with a simple search box and an input button.  2 things happen when the user does a search:

1. A new tab is opened and it searches Google for whatever they typed
   in.
2. The page they were just on (where they did the search from) refreshes, and has a 50% chance of triggering an SQL query.

To prevent botting, I want to put a CAPTCHA on this SQL query.

The problem I'm currently having is that the CAPTCHA instantly fails. I'm assuming it's because the first form fired off. It's kicking back "incorrect solution" which is what lead me to believe that.

**Here's the current structure.**

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="" target="" onsubmit="refresh(this);">

<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" /> 
<input style="color: #cc423f; font-weight:bold; padding: 7px 15px;" name="search" type="submit" value="Search" /> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh(a){
// location.reload(true);
window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+a.q.value);
}
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['q'])){
if (mt_rand(0, 1) === 0) { // 50% chance of this event happening

// BEGIN SolveMedia CAPTCHA form
echo "<form id=\"solve4points\" method=\"post\" action=\"\" target=\"\" onsubmit=\"refresh(this);\">"; ?>
<?php echo solvemedia_get_html("XI.WRU97NXJXuJWRfL0FajiudOutJyDC"); //this displays SolveMedia CAPTCHA widget
echo "<br /><input style=\"color: #cc423f; font-weight:bold; padding: 7px 15px;\" type=\"submit\" name=\"solve4points\" value=\"Get Points!\" />
</form>";

} // end SolveMedia CAPTCHA form

else { // 50% chance of this event happening
echo "<br /><p>Nope, not today!</p>";
}
}

if(isset($_POST['solve4points'])){
echo solvemedia_get_html("XI.WRU97NXJXuJWRfL0FajiudOutJyDC");
require_once("/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/solvemedia/solvemedia.php");
$privkey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // API keys for CAPTCHA
$hashkey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";// API keys for CAPTCHA

$solvemedia_response = solvemedia_check_answer($privkey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["adcopy_challenge"], $_POST["adcopy_response"], $hashkey);

if (!$solvemedia_response->is_valid) { //if user fails to complete CAPTCHA correctly, do this
print "Error: ".$solvemedia_response->error;
}

else {//if user completed CAPTCHA correctly, do this
mysql_query......

} 
}
?>
```

For security reasons, I've removed the database connection and API key information, but I know that stuff is correct.

Comment: cant work out what the google searches point is

Comment: Without going into much details, users can search the web from the website. By doing so, they have a 50% chance of having an event trigger on their account via an SQL query which I've left out since that bit is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should not call
`solvemedia_get_html("XI.WRU97NXJXuJWRfL0FajiudOutJyDC");`
2 times.

You call this method just before checking the answer.
I don't know  solvemedia captcha ( i used the one from google recaptcha) , never used it, but maybe calling it twice, just make invalid your last response because you just asked for a new media to solve from the same ip address.